# Obtener campos que contengan una frase con Match() Against()

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy tratando de obtener los libros cuyos titulo contenga lo que ingresa el usuario.

Suponiendo que tengo los siguientes libros:

- Arboles
- Los aviones
- Había una vez trus

Suponiendo que el usuario ingresaba la letra `a`, antes lo resolvía usando la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT title 
    FROM Books 
    WHERE title LIKE "%a%";
```

Lo cual me retornaba todos los libros.

Luego, investigando, encontré que la función `Match Against` es mucho más rápida que `like` así que traté de migrarlo, pero para mi sorpresa cuando hago la query:

```
SELECT title 
    FROM Books 
    WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST ('a' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

No retorna nada, ya que no contiene la frase completa `a`. Probé sin éxito con la query:

```
SELECT title 
    FROM Books 
    WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST ('*a*' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Hay alguna forma de hacer que retorne los libros cuando el titulo contiene la frase, ya sea de forma exacta o no?

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El `MATCH` `AGAINST` hace busquedas muy similares a un buscador web, es decir, busca por palabras completas, y no por su contenido. Ahora bien, utilizar por ejemplo `'a*'` si es permitido ya que se usa para buscar las palabras que empiecen con A, el `'*a*'` no lo es. En ese caso si tienes que usar el tradicional `LIKE`.

Comment: Gracias por responder, voy a ver como me manejo. Me parece que voy a terminar optando por un servicio de Cloud Search como el de Amazon. Saludos!

Answer (score 2):

La función `MATCH ( ) AGAINST ( )` busca coincidencias de *"texto completo"* (full-text) y sí puede ser más rápida que una búsqueda utilizando el operador `LIKE`, siempre y cuando se cumplan ciertas condiciones.  Primordialmente que exista un índice de tipo `FULLTEXT` en la(s) columna(s) que contienen los elementos de texto que representan el universo de las búsquedas.  Cuando se utiliza la modalidad `IN BOOLEAN MODE` no es necesario que exista un índice de tipo `FULLTEXT` pero las búsquedas serán más lentas.  Los índices `FULLTEXT` solo se pueden crear en tablas MyISAM hasta la versión 5.5 y a partir de la versión 5.6 ya se permite su creación en tablas InnoDB.

Por otra parte, las búsquedas de texto completo tienen restricciones en cuanto a la longitud mínima de las palabras que se consideran válidas controlado por el parámetro de configuración `ft_min_word_len` cuyo valor por omisión es 4 caracteres.  Si se cambia el valor de este parámetro se deben reconstruir los índices de tipo `FULLTEXT`.  Además existe una lista de palabras que son ignoradas en las búsquedas de texto completo conocidas en inglés como [*stop words*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-stopwords.html).

Ahora bien, en la modalidad `IN BOOLEAN MODE` el asterisco solo puede ir *al final* de una cadena de caracteres y significa que se incluyan en el resultado registros que contengan palabras que comiencen con el prefijo indicado antes del asterisco.  En otras palabras `AGAINST('a*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)` es similar a `LIKE 'a%'`.  En este caso no importa el parámetro de la longitud mínima ya que el prefijo no indica una palabra completa, sino únicamente un prefijo.

Me parece que la funcionalidad que buscas sería utilizar la modalidad de lenguaje natural `AGAINST('texto tecleado por el usuario' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)`, el cual te generaría un resultado ordenado por un factor de coincidencia que colocaría al principio los registros que contengan el texto más parecido a la condición.  Sin embargo, para esto se requiere la creación de un índice `FULLTEXT` en las columnas que vas a utilizar para las búsquedas, con las restricciones que mencioné anteriormente.

La modalidad `IN BOOLEAN MODE` ofrece *operadores* que puedes utilizar para indicar el tratamiento de las palabras:

- `+` Indica que el texto debe contener la palabra.
- `-` Indica que el texto NO debe contener la palabra.
- `>` Indica que si el texto contiene la palabra le da más peso.
- `<` Indica que si el texto contiene la palabra le da menos peso.
- `~` Indica que el peso de la palabra es negativo, funciona como un `-` suave, que no elimina la coincidencia.
- `*` A diferencia de los otros operadores este solo va al final para denotar un prefijo.
- `()` Los paréntesis se utilizan para agrupar condiciones.
- `""` El texto entrecomillado se busca de manera literal, solo se incluyen las coincidencias exactas.

Más información en la [documentación de referencia](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html).

Comment: Gracias por responder y por la info extra que le agregaste!

Answer (score 0):

Lo que debes hacer es que a los campos que quieres realizar una búsqueda `MATCH()` y `AGAINST()` cambiarlos por `FULLTEXT`.

Por ejemplo, si yo tengo una tabla llamado `producto` y sus campos son `id_producto`, `nombre_producto` y `precio_producto`, lo que debes hacer es, cuando ya lo tengas creado dentro del MySQL hacer lo siguiente:

```
ALTER TABLE producto ADD FULLTEXT(nombre_producto)
```

Aplicando la línea anterior, el campo `nombre_producto` ya estaría quedando listo para usar `MATCH()` y `AGAINST()`.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar una estructura if para si es una palabra usar like y si es una frase match..

```
// verifica si hay contenido
if ($busqueda<>''){
  //CUENTA EL NUMERO DE PALABRAS
  $trozos=explode(" ",$busqueda);
  $numero=count($trozos);
  if ($numero==1) {
    //SI SOLO HAY UNA PALABRA DE BUSQUEDA SE ESTABLECE UNA INSTRUCION CON LIKE
    $peticion="aqui pones la peticion con like";

  } elseif ($numero>1) {
    //SI HAY UNA FRASE SE UTILIZA EL ALGORTIMO DE BUSQUEDA AVANZADO DE MATCH AGAINST
    //busqueda de frases con mas de una palabra y un algoritmo especializado
    $peticion="aqui pones la peticion con match";
  }
}
```

Saludos